# Шейдер не использует окружающий свет

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Мне нужно, чтобы мой шейдер увеличивал яркость в зависимости от падающего на него света

[image: Проблема с монотонностью граней]
[image: Грани различимы из-за падающего на них света]

```
Shader "Mobile/CustomFogCube"
{
Properties
{
_FogStart("Fog Start", float) = 0 //объявляем наши новые переменные для тумана
_FogEnd ("Fog End", float) = 2000

_MainTex1 ("TX1", 2D) = "white" {}
_Color ("Color", Color) = (0,0,0,0)
_Scale ("Scale", float) = 0.5
}
SubShader
{
    Tags{ "RenderType" = "Opaque"  "LIGHTMODE"="Always"}
    Fog{ Mode off }
    LOD 200

    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert  
        #pragma fragment frag Lambert 
        #pragma multi_compile _ LIGHTMAP_ON
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        #pragma target 2.0

        sampler2D _MainTex1;
        float1 _Scale;
        half4 _Color;

        half _FogStart;  //определяем новые переменные в рамках CGPROGRAM
        half _FogEnd;

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float4 color : COLOR;
            float4 uv : TEXCOORD1;
        };


        struct v2f
        {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;

            float4 uv : TEXCOORD1;
            half fog : TEXCOORD2;  //добавляем новую переменную для расчета расстояния отображения тумана и последующей передачи в fragment функцию
            float4 color : COLOR;
            half3 viewDir : TEXCOORD3;
        };


        v2f vert(appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;

            o.color = v.color;//fixed4(225,225,0,225); // Цвет   ОШИБКА ГДЕ-ТО ЗДЕСЬ
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            //lightmaps
            o.uv.xy = v.uv.xy* unity_LightmapST.xy + unity_LightmapST.zw;
            //fog высчитываем положение тумана в зависимости от заданных значений
            half fogz = UnityObjectToViewPos(v.vertex).z;
            o.fog = saturate((fogz + _FogStart) / (_FogStart - _FogEnd));
            float3 worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;
            o.viewDir = -(normalize(UnityWorldSpaceViewDir(worldPos)));
            return o;
        }

        half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
        {
            UNITY_SETUP_STEREO_EYE_INDEX_POST_VERTEX(i);

            float4 clr = tex2D (_MainTex1, i.uv * _Scale);
            fixed4 c = clr.rgba * _Color;
            //lightmaps
            #ifdef LIGHTMAP_ON
              fixed4 lm = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2D(unity_Lightmap, i.uv.xy);
            c.rgb *= lm.rgb * 4;
            #endif
            //fog заменяем плавно цвет поверхности на цвет кубомапы (он же наш туман). Кубомапу нужно задать в настройках освещение (Lighting > Scene > Environment Reflection > Source = Custom > Cubemap = Ваша кубомапа)
            half4 fogCube = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEXCUBE(unity_SpecCube0, i.viewDir);
            return lerp(c, fogCube, i.fog);
        }
        ENDCG
    }

}
Fallback "Mobile/VertexLit"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на [этом](https://russianblogs.com/article/480391477/) сайте.

```
Shader "Mobile/CustomFogCube"
{
Properties
{
_FogStart("Fog Start", float) = 0 //объявляем наши новые переменные для тумана
_FogEnd ("Fog End", float) = 2000

_MainTex1 ("TX1", 2D) = "white" {}
_Color ("Color", Color) = (0,0,0,0)
_Scale ("Scale", float) = 0.5

_Diffuse("Diffuse", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
}
SubShader
{
    Tags{ "RenderType" = "Opaque"}
    Fog{ Mode off }
    LOD 200

    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert 
        #pragma fragment frag  
        #pragma multi_compile _ LIGHTMAP_ON
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"    
        #include "Lighting.cginc" 
        #pragma target 2.0

        sampler2D _MainTex1;
        float1 _Scale;
        half4 _Color;
        fixed4 _Diffuse;

        half _FogStart;  //определяем новые переменные в рамках CGPROGRAM
        half _FogEnd;

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float4 color : COLOR;
            float4 uv : TEXCOORD1;
            float3 normal : NORMAL;
        };


        struct v2f
        {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float4 uv : TEXCOORD1;
            half fog : TEXCOORD2;  //добавляем новую переменную для расчета расстояния отображения тумана и последующей передачи в fragment функцию
            float4 color : COLOR;
            half3 viewDir : TEXCOORD3;

            float3 worldNormal : TEXCOORD0;
        };


        v2f vert(appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;

            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            
            // Transform the vertex from object space to projection space
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            // Transform the normal from object space to world space
            o.worldNormal = mul(v.normal, (float3x3)unity_WorldToObject);

            o.color = v.color;
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            //lightmaps
            o.uv.xy = v.uv.xy* unity_LightmapST.xy + unity_LightmapST.zw;
            //fog высчитываем положение тумана в зависимости от заданных значений
            half fogz = UnityObjectToViewPos(v.vertex).z;
            o.fog = saturate((fogz + _FogStart) / (_FogStart - _FogEnd));
            float3 worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;
            o.viewDir = -(normalize(UnityWorldSpaceViewDir(worldPos)));
            return o;
        }

        half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
        {           
            UNITY_SETUP_STEREO_EYE_INDEX_POST_VERTEX(i);

            fixed3 ambient = UNITY_LIGHTMODEL_AMBIENT.xyz;              
            // Get the normal in world space
            fixed3 worldNormal = normalize(i.worldNormal);
            // Get the light direction in world space
            fixed3 worldLightDir = normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);             
            // Compute diffuse term
            fixed3 diffuse = _LightColor0.rgb * _Diffuse.rgb * saturate(dot(worldNormal, worldLightDir));
            fixed4 lw = fixed4(diffuse + ambient,1);

            float4 clr = tex2D (_MainTex1, i.uv * _Scale);
            fixed4 c = clr.rgba * _Color * lw;
            //lightmaps
            #ifdef LIGHTMAP_ON
              fixed4 lm = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2D(unity_Lightmap, i.uv.xy);
            c.rgb *= lm.rgb * 4;
            #endif
            //fog заменяем плавно цвет поверхности на цвет кубомапы (он же наш туман). Кубомапу нужно задать в настройках освещение (Lighting > Scene > Environment Reflection > Source = Custom > Cubemap = Ваша кубомапа)
            half4 fogCube = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEXCUBE(unity_SpecCube0, i.viewDir);
            return lerp(c, fogCube, i.fog);
        }
        ENDCG
    }

}
Fallback "Mobile/VertexLit"
}
```